# jquery mobile load page external into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

How do insert the external code of register.html page in a `div` when  when it finishes successfully my call `ajax`?

```
function onSuccess(data, status)
    {

         $.mobile.pageContainer = $("#content").pagecontainer();
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "register.html");
    }

    function onError(data, status)
    {
        // handle an error
    }
```

I use `pageContainer` but not load the html in `#content div`

Comment: always make corrections to the text, but never one that answers the questions up here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use enhanceWithin() otherwise JQuery mobile enhancement won't be performed on the new content:

```
$.get('pagename.html', function (response) {
        $('#result').html(response).enhanceWithin();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If using JQuery, you can load in external pages/markup using the load method. This will allow you to then output it into a div.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

For more info, see

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: the load() method is of jquery not jquery mobile and when i load the page in a div my div lost the style of a div #content of jquery mobile